# Keras run predict_generator on multiple GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am generating bottlenecks for a VGG16 model. I have a lot of data and am using 6 GPUs. It seems to be simple enough to train with multiple GPUs as of Keras 2.0.9. I tried just running `multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=6)` and then running `predict_generator`. And although my program is shown running on each GPU( Using nvidia-smi ) it seems to be generating on CPU. Is there any way for me to easily run predict_generator on multiple GPUs? (Although I have a bad feeling Ill have to 'rewrite' my own version of multi_gpu_model), If I was to implement this myself would the best way to do this be to make a thread for each GPU that will run the `predict_generator` on a separate batch?

Sorry If I have missed something obvious.